# How to go back to the first if statement when no other choice was inputted

Tags: python, game-development

```
answer_A = ["A", "a"]
answer_B = ["B", "b"]
answer_C = ["C", "c"]
yes = ["Y", "y", "yes"]
no = ["N", "n", "no"]

print("################################")
print("#                              #")
print("#    Welcome to PyLandia       #")
print("#                              #")
print("################################")
print()
print()
print("Wha... What? Where am I?")
print()
print("*You look around to see a thick forest surrounding you.*")
print()
startGame = input("Begin the game of PyLandia? [Y/N]: ")


if startGame in yes:
    intro()
elif startGame in no:
    print("Ok, Maybe next time!")
```

I cant figure this error out! What i HAVE is that on the if and elif, when a user types Y or N, it will give the appropriate answer. That is working fine. What i NEED to add though is that if someone accidentaly typed "U" for example, it would say "No Y or N found! Try again!" Then it will go back to the first if statement to enter y/n again. I have tried looking at older articles saying to use def, or while loops, but NOTHING WORKS! i want to make a game, and i will need to implement the error retry code into EVERY QUESTION! someone please help! i cant solve it :(

Comment: `while loops, but NOTHING WORKS` be sure that works ! Can you show your non working solution using *while* for instance ?

Answer (score 0):

I would replace the bottom part to contain this:

```py
while True:
    startGame = input("Begin the game of PyLandia? [Y/N]: ")
    if startGame in yes:
        intro()
        break
    elif startGame in no:
        print("Ok, Maybe next time!")
        break
    else:
        print("No Y or N found! Try again!")
```

Here's the full code:

```py
answer_A = ["A", "a"]
answer_B = ["B", "b"]
answer_C = ["C", "c"]
yes = ["Y", "y", "yes"]
no = ["N", "n", "no"]

print("################################")
print("#                              #")
print("#    Welcome to PyLandia       #")
print("#                              #")
print("################################")
print()
print()
print("Wha... What? Where am I?")
print()
print("*You look around to see a thick forest surrounding you.*")
print()

while True:
    startGame = input("Begin the game of PyLandia? [Y/N]: ")
    if startGame in yes:
        intro()
        break
    elif startGame in no:
        print("Ok, Maybe next time!")
        break
    else:
        print("No Y or N found! Try again!")
```

Comment: you missed a *break* and more

Comment: Ah thank you so much @pradhyum R ! The only problem is that with your code, the first time i put an error, it doesnt say "try again" it just restarts. But the SECOND time, it says "try again!" as well as with the others

Comment: @hackerkitteh you are wrong, the code above cannot have the behavior you speak about

Comment: I have tested it, and I think it does do what you want it to do.

Comment: but you must test again `startGame in yes` after the loop to do the rest of the code or no

Comment: I think I wasn't clear when answering this. I meant to define startGame in the loop, not out of it below the print statements.

Comment: i dont understand.... sorry im a beginner

Comment: i need some more help... can someone please give the fixed code? Im still learning so it would be good for me to look over it and understand it

Comment: OH MY GOD! Thank you so much! Thank you for helping me have a good day